# Left Join with multiple tables - "ORA-00904:invalid identifier" error

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to find all the records from Table 2, which are not present either in Table 3 or Table 4. I have to use Table 1 in my query, because it gives me the keys to join Table 2 with Table 3 and Table 4.

But, I keep getting `"ORA-00904:invalid identifier" error on "T1.COL3"`

Below is my query:

```
Select T1.COL1 FROM  Tab1 T1 , Tab2 T2
        LEFT JOIN Tab3 T3 ON (T2. COL1=T1.COL1 AND T3. COL2=T1.COL3)
        LEFT JOIN Tab4 T4 ON (T2. COL1=T1.COL1 AND T4. COL2=T1.COL3)
where  ( T3. COL2 IS NULL and T4. COL2 IS NULL);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide a schema/column list for the tables? Thanks. The error looks a bit like COL3 does not exist on table 1...

Answer (score 4):

I'm dealing with a similar error due to a BUG in oracle query optimizer.

However as I see in your query mixing ansi sql (left outer join) with "," indicated joins is, at least, tricky.

I believe in your case, having T1 before the "," makes it is not visible in the ON clause that is interpreted to include only T2, T3 and T4.

I would try to wrap it like this

```
Select T1.COL1 FROM  Tab1 T1  inner join Tab2 T2 on T2. COL1=T1.COL1
LEFT JOIN Tab3 T3 ON  T3. COL2=T1.COL3
LEFT JOIN Tab4 T4 ON T4. COL2=T1.COL3
where  ( T3. COL2 IS NULL and T4. COL2 IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm), the `ORA-00904` error means that a column name is invalid or missing.

In your case this is an invalid name. As the documentation states, names must consist only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #. Otherwise the name must be enclosed in double quotation marks. So try enclosing the names with double quotes.

Comment: Hi,  That is the problem. Actually, the column name is valid. when I select Col 3 from Tab1, I get values. Also, it works with simple join queries. But, today when I wrote the above query, it gives me this error !!!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. But you're saying enclosing `T1.COL3` with double quotes didn't solve your problem?